# Looking for a (preferably digital) collection of McCarthy speeches (transcripts)

Tags: united-states, political-history, language, communism, resource

I am analysing the history of demagogy and it's rhetoric using modern data science. I have acquired some collections of speeches dating back to George Washington, but unfortunately I have not been able to find anything beyond "Enemies from Within" from McCarthy.

I know that there are transcripts from Senate hearings in which he appeared, but he doesn't say very much in those so they are of no big help.

He was known for his extreme anti-communist public speeches, so it seems odd that there are not transcripts of those. Maybe this community can help me out?

Comment: I don't understand that close votes for off-topic. It is a history question and the askee seems to have already looked it up. So why the votes ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. - This could arguably be considered a request for references. I think the latest most authoritative meta article we have on the subject is [here](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited). This question seems smack in the middle of the two extreme (fine vs. not) examples given in the top answer there.

Comment: @T.E.D. Ah, yes.It fulfills the most upvoted criterion, a request for primary sources which cannot be circumvented in any way. So at least my opinion is that it is definitely on-topic.

Comment: @ThorstenS. - I obviously didn't think it was a big problem either (since I answered). However, I could see an argument that there are potentially multiple possible different "right" answers, which is contrary to a specifically called-out feature of the "good" example. Still, its clearly not down in the realm of "Everybody please argue over your favorite book on X".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The University of Marquette seems to have [a lot of McCarthy material](http://cdm16280.contentdm.oclc.org/cdm/search/searchterm/joseph%20mccarthy/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/title/ad/asc/cosuppress/1) digitized and online. I believe they have even more [material that isn't](http://www.marquette.edu/library/archives/Mss/JRM/JRM-main.shtml) (yet?) digitized.

Comment: Oh my! That is a lot indeed. Thank you very much!